# NWPath.status shows unsatisfied on device, statisfied on simulator

Tags: apple-watch, watchos

I am encountering an issue when attempting to verify access to the internet from WatchOS on a physical device. Running the code below on a physical device always shows "Not Connected." However, running on the simulator shows "Connected."

```
import Foundation
import Network

class NetworkMonitor: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var isConnected: Bool = false
    @Published var currentNetworkType: NWInterface.InterfaceType = .other
    
    private let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
   
    init() {
        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { [weak self] path in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.networkStatusDidChange(path)
            }
        }
        monitor.start(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))
    }
  
    private func networkStatusDidChange(_ path: NWPath) {
        isConnected = path.status == .satisfied
        currentNetworkType = path.availableInterfaces.first?.type ?? .other
    }
    
    deinit {
        monitor.cancel()
    }

}

import Foundation
import Network

class NetworkMonitor: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var isConnected: Bool = false
    @Published var currentNetworkType: NWInterface.InterfaceType = .other
    
    private let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
   
    init() {
        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { [weak self] path in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.networkStatusDidChange(path)
            }
        }
        monitor.start(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))
    }
  
    private func networkStatusDidChange(_ path: NWPath) {
        isConnected = path.status == .satisfied
        currentNetworkType = path.availableInterfaces.first?.type ?? .other
    }
    
    deinit {
        monitor.cancel()
    }

}
```